# Matlab: How to see a simulations results

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am finding out how to use the 'From workspace' and 'to workspace' blocks in order to perform a simulation in a .mdl file by doing a small exercise as you see in the picture below.
I get something from simulink to workspace, a variable called 'simout'
but I don´t know how to acces to this variable.
Does anyone could tell me how to see the results of my simulation?
I enter the name of the variable 'simout' but I don´t get nothing, only this message:

```
simout = 

     time: []
  signals: [1x1 struct]
blockName: 'Fromworkspace/To Workspace'
```

Thank you so much!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data are in `simout.signals.values` and the times are in `simout.time`.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the solution:

[image]

If I select the variable output format as an array, then when I wrote the name of the variable in workspace then the numerics value are printed.

Comment: Well, It might not be a good idea to use just an array. If you plan to use the "From Workspace" block elsewhere in the Simulink model, its expects that variable is a structure. You could access the values as Nzbuu mentions use simout.signals.values